# add string with a command for .bashrc

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal

I am trying to create a alias in `.bashrc` that goes something like this:

```
alias www="open http://localhost/~Sites/;basename $(pwd)"
```

So for instance, if I did the following in terminal:

```
cd ~/Sites/project1
www
```

I want the browser to open with the address `http://localhost/~Sites/project1` but I am having trouble getting `basename $(pwd)` to run.

What is wrong with the syntax? How do I add a string and a simple command into a single alias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
alias www='open "http://localhost/~Sites/$(basename $PWD)"'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a function instead, aliases aren't very featureful.

```
www() {
  open "http://localhost/~Sites/$(basename $PWD)"
}
```

Or better, have the function do both:

```
www() {
  dir=$1
  cd ~/Sites/"$1"
  open "http://localhost/~Sites/$1"
}
```

Comment: thanks! although the above works fine, @robertklep's answer works as an alias.

Comment: It does in this case, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want a `;`.  You want the output of `basename` to go on that command line:

```
alias www='open http://localhost/~Sites/$(basename $(pwd))'
```